# How do I scroll through my list of processes when I use top on terminal (mac)?

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, top

When I use top not all the processes fit on one page. How do I scroll through them?

Comment: Sorry, but this is lacking a bit of sense to me. Shouldn't there be something inherent within top that allows you see all processes which are running? It seems odd that the data would be truncated with no option to see the entire list.

Answer (score 2):

`htop` [can be compiled for OS X](http://geektechnica.com/2009/07/how-to-install-htop-on-osx/) and supports scrolling.

Comment: this link is dead.

Comment: Found a fantastically easy install for htop. Thanks for the recommendation Dennis! http://themainframe.ca/2011/06/29/install-htop-on-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK top doesn't scroll through pages. Use

```
ps auxwf
```

and read

```
man ps
```

Comment: `ps: illegal option -- f`

Comment: The just try ps alone and start adding the other flags. What f does is to show child processes in a tree with their parents. Without you would get processes ordered by number. Again, read **man ps**

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ps.1.html

Comment: That comment is just fyi so you can e.g. edit your response, as the question specifically mentions OS X, and the flag doesn't work there.